# "TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function"

Tags: node.js, express

Serving the index.html works fine, but I cannot serve the PDF.

I'm on the latest version of express. I've double checked the path names.

The code for these routes is exactly the same, why doesn't it work?

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/resume', (res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/resume.pdf'));
app.get(/.*/, (res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
```

[image: Project physical structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `req` to the function arguments as well:

`app.get(/.*/, (req,res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));`